# Problems combining packages newlfm with babel[spanish]

Tags: babel, spanish, newlfm

I am writing a letter with package newlfm and babel[spanish], and some construction from spanish do not work commands from newlfm. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,busletter,spanish]{newlfm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % Should not be used with LuaTeX  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   

\usepackage{babel}   

\namefrom{%
          Dr. N. N.   \\
          N"o pasaporte: 1234556789 \\  %%% do not work...
          }
\addrfrom{Ciudad}
\addrto{%
        Señora: \\
        M. Sc. M. M.  \\
        Universidad de la Ciudad
        }
\dateset{8 de marzo de 2016}
\greetto{}
\closeline{Sin otro particular, le saluda atentamente,}  
\PhrRegard{Ref.}
\regarding{Aceptación invitación}  

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

En referencia a nota N"o 12344321 %%% This works
acepto la invitación a ...

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

It is the construction :   N"o   which construct V with an o in upper index position, from the spanish option to babel, which do work as expected when used in the letter body, but do not work when used inside the argument to \namefrom{}.

What is the problem, and how to resolve it?

Comment: never apply `\protect` to a `{` that will make all kinds of strange things happen. (`\protect` does not take an argument so that _only_ applies to `{` not to the whole group)

Comment: Will remove \protect then, it works the same bad without protect!

Comment: It's not a specific `newlfm` problem; `"` becomes a shorthand only after `\begin{document}`. So just move up `\begin{document}`.

Comment: That did the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

babel shortcuts only work after `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,busletter,spanish]{newlfm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % Should not be used with LuaTeX  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   

\usepackage{babel}   

\begin{document}
\namefrom{%
          Dr. N. N.   \\
          N"o pasaporte: 1234556789 \\  %%% do not work...
          }
\addrfrom{Ciudad}
\addrto{%
        Señora: \\
        M. Sc. M. M.  \\
        Universidad de la Ciudad
        }
\dateset{8 de marzo de 2016}
\greetto{}
\closeline{Sin otro particular, le saluda atentamente,}  
\PhrRegard{Ref.}
\regarding{Aceptación invitación}  


\begin{newlfm}

En referencia a nota N"o 12344321 %%% This works
acepto la invitación a ...

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Or simpler, as you are using utf8 encoding you could just enter the character directly.

Comment: Thanks!  For entering the glyphs directly, do not know how to do that ... Any pointer to website about input methods?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I assumed that if you were typing the language you'd have keyboard with them on:-)  It's Unicode U+00BA so in emacs `C-x8 ret ba` will work, but other systems will have other ways   or just cut and paste this: N.º :-)

Comment: Thanks, I am writing spanish on a norwegian keyboard ...